# Nodemailer 24 hour sending limit

Tags: node.js, email, outlook, nodemailer, godaddy-api

I have an email account from godaddy hosted on outlook. I'm using nodemailer to automatically send emails from it, using smtpout.secureserver.net.

I emailed 25 different people with nodemailer, and not I get this error:
"User me@site.com has exceeded its 24-hour sending limit. Messages to 25 recipients out of 25 allowed have been sent"

But if I go into outlook and manually send more emails, they get delivered without issue.

What's going on? I believe godaddy has a cap at 250 for my plan, but I definitely haven't hit that, and I can still send them fine from the outlook app, just not from nodemailer.

thanks!

Comment: Did you get any solution

Comment: Any answer to this question as i also have repeated same steps and same issue.