# Nodemailer - exceeded its 24-hour sending limit

Tags: nodemailer, godaddy-api

I was searching in other questions, but there were never answered ([Nodemailer 24 hour sending limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61814659/nodemailer-24-hour-sending-limit)).

I have same problem as this guy. When I try to send more than 25 emails per a day I got error message

`Error: Mail command failed: 550 User test@test.test has exceeded its 24-hour sending limit. Messages to 52 recipients out of 25 allowed have been sent. Relay quota will reset in 23.50 hours.`

I tried to contact goDaddy, but they said that it is problem of my mail server. But I am using smtpout.europe.secureserver.net which they provide on https://uk.godaddy.com/help/server-and-port-settings-for-workspace-email-6949

Also I did not found any solution in nodemailer docs.

Thank you!

Comment: the problem has no relation with nodeMailer

Comment: If you're sending anything like bulk email, you need to use a dedicated service like sendgrid, not a host-service-provided setup.

Comment: Moukim, I thought that when the GoDaddy daily limit is 250 and I use nodemailer that it is the problem.

Comment: O. Jones, ok, I'll study the sendgrid you mentioned.

Comment: O. Jones, sendgrid really solve my problem. Thank you.